# Notepad ++ "Function List" as a source code navigator?

Tags: php, ide, notepad++

Is it possible, using the "Function List" plugin in Notepad++,  to  work on all php files of an entire project (gathered in a folder) and then be allowed to a source code navigation through all the elements (Class, Function, Variable, Constants, etc.) ?